# Accesing json data sent through a post request in Apache Camel

Tags: post, amazon-s3, apache-camel, apache-camel-aws

I am new to Apache Camel. I want to access the data sent through a post request in order to download a file from S3. This is the router that I wrote.

```
public static class HelloRoute extends RouteBuilder {
       
        @Override
        public void configure() {
            rest("/")
                .post("file-from-s3")
                    .route()
                    .setHeader(AWS2S3Constants.KEY, constant("filename"))
                    .to("aws2-s3://bucketnameaccessKey=INSERT&secretKey=INSERT&region=INSERT&operation=getObject")
                    .to("file:/tmp/")
                    .endRest();
        }
```

The corresponding json data that will be sent ->

```
{
     "filename" : "test.txt",
     "bucketname": "testbucket",
     "accessKey" : "key",
     "secretKey" : "key2",
     "region"    : "region"

}
```

How to do I access these json values in the code above?

Comment: The request will be framed by the AWS component within the SDK, try enabling debug logs for the AWS component.

Answer (score 0):

You need to unmarshal the JSON request data first. You can choose from a variety of libs and ways to do this, check out [the Camel docs for JSON](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/json.html).

Then the message body contains the structure you unmarshalled your data to (POJO, Map). So you can access it on various ways by using [Simple](https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/languages/simple-language.html) directly in the Route or a [Bean method](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/bean-binding.html) that is called from the route etc.